# submit textbox values from html table to database using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have two database tables called Trick1 and Trick2.

Trick1 table
ID | std | batch

21 | X   |  B
22 | X   |  B
23 | X   |  B
24 | X   |  B
25 | X   |  B
26 | X   |  B

Trick2 Table

ID | std | batch | marks

Here is the HTML table with code in which the data are taken from Trick1 database Table and new column is created called MARKS with textbox and redirect to page tableDemo2.jsp.

```
<form method="post" action="tableDemo2.jsp">
<table style="border : 1px solid blue;">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>STD</th>
        <th>BATCH</th>
        <th>MARKS</th>
    </tr>
<%
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mcc", "root","");

            String query = "select * from trick1";
            Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
         %>     
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("id") %></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>">
                <td><%=rs.getString("std") %></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="stds" value="<%=rs.getString("std")%>">
                <td><%=rs.getString("batch") %></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="batchs" value="<%=rs.getString("batch")%>">
                <td><input type="number" name="numb"></td>
            </tr>
        <%
            }  }
            catch(SQLException se){
                System.out.println("SQL Exception : "+se.getMessage());
            }
         %>
   </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

This is table created in HTML

[image: This is table created in HTM1L]

What I want is, all the four columns data of HTML table should be inserted in Trick2 Database Table

Below is the page tableDemo2.jsp

```
<%
    String id = request.getParameter("ids");
    String std = request.getParameter("stds");
    String batch = request.getParameter("batchs");
    String[] marks = request.getParameterValues("numb");
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(marks));

    try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mcc", "root","");
         Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
         stmt.executeUpdate("insert into trick2 values('"+id+"','"+std+"','"+batch+"','"+marks+"')");

         response.sendRedirect("tableDemo.jsp");
         }
        catch(SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception : "+se.getMessage());
        }
%>
```

Where i went wrong. Please help me.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should avoid database settings and database code at all inside your .jsp-files. This should go to the server side.

Read about jstl to avoid mixing serverside with frontend side.

I see you are trying to get the ids but are using

```
String ids = request.getParameter("ids")
```

You should use the same as for marks like

```
String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("ids");
```

Do the same for the other variables you want to get the values.

And also read about SQL-injection to understand why this line is not safe:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into trick2 values('"+id+"','"+std+"','"+batch+"','"+marks+"')");
```

Use a PreparedStatemnt for that:

```
String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, SALARY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES (?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT)) {
preparedStatement.setString(1, "mkyong");
preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(2, new BigDecimal(799.88));
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Hi rhenesys, to comment on your answer: code that resides in JSP files ist executed on the serverside - the database settings will not be visible or executed on the client side. 
But - I totally agree with you, that JSP files are not a good location for database logic.

Comment: if i make an array of ids, String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("ids");   so its showing me an error in this, preparedStatement.setString(1, ids); The error is , The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String[])]

Comment: This is just a simple iteration over the elements from the array or arrays, if you want to get/send all of them. It seems you are trying to pass the whole array, what it will not work. Read about how an array works and loops.